# Human readable directory tree with org-attach

Tags: org-mode, files

By default, org-attach.el names project folders, using a UUID scheme, which is paired with headlines in org-mode, via the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer.

I would love to find a way to make this directory structure human readable, so that it can be accessed outside of org-mode (e.g., folder names are matched to headline names). So this outline structure:

```
* This headline
  ** This sub-headline 1
  ** This sub-headline 2
* This second headline
```

matches to the directory structure:

```
- This headline
  - This sub-headline 1
  - This sub-headline 2
- This second headline
```

Obviously, this presents an issue, should either of these get renamed. But maybe there is another way to get this done with UUIDs? Some possibilities:

1. Match a UUID in the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer to a UUID in the folder's metadata (Spotlight comments on the Mac come to mind)
2. Create a second folder structure via sim-links, that updates when `org-attach-sync` is called.

Any thoughts, ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I just posted the question on the org-mailing list as well - let's hope for an answer.

Comment: `org-attach` wiil respect each entry's `ATTACH_DIR`  property. Of course you'd have to add that property yourself.

Answer (score 5):

#### Define `ATTACH_DIR` Property Under Each Heading to Set an Human Readable Directory Path for Attachments

1. Place cursor, a.k.a point, on heading.

   For this example, choose `This headline`

   ```
   * This headline
   ** This sub-headline 1
   ** This sub-headline 2
   * This second headline
   ```
2. Press key chord <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>This headline</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   > **Note:** You will need to remove the default full path to make directory relative to org file.

   The example should look similar to the following:

   ```
   * This headline
     :PROPERTIES:
     :ATTACH_DIR: This headline
     :END:
   ** This sub-headline 1
   ** This sub-headline 2
   * This second headline
   ```
3. Attach files by pressing key chord <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>.

   For example, I attached file named `junk001.org` under `This headline`

   ```
   * This headline :ATTACH:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ATTACH_DIR: This headline
   :Attachments: junk001.org
   :END:
   ** This sub-headline 1
   ** This sub-headline 2
   * This second headline
   ```

   Which created the file structure below:

   ```
   .
   ├── example1.org
   └── This headline
       └── junk001.org

   1 directory, 2 files
   ```
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for other headings and files.

   If the directory paths change in future it should fairly straightforward to maintain paths by updating `ATTACH_DIR` values and renaming existing directories to match. It should be possible to automate updating directories to match heading and migrate files.

   ```
   * This headline :ATTACH:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ATTACH_DIR: This headline
   :Attachments: junk001.org
   :END:
   ** This sub-headline 1 :ATTACH:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ATTACH_DIR: This headline/This sub-headline 1
   :Attachments: junk002.org
   :END:
   ** This sub-headline 2
   * This second headline
   ```

   Which matches the directory tree below:

   ```
   .
   ├── example1.org
   └── This headline
       ├── junk001.org
       └── This sub-headline 1
           └── junk002.org


   2 directories, 3 files
   ```

Hope that helped!

---

> **Note:** This answer was validated using the following software:
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   org mode version: 9.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is helpful to just say- I don't think that org attach has this capacity.  Meaning, I have synced directories, but it does not recursively define a subtree based on the structure of the attached file.

I was trying to do this for some of my source... If someone wants to prove me wrong then go for it.  But when I attach and sync the root directory and have the inherit flag set, all of the sub-directories do not get recursively generated in my org file as nodes.